# I used eclipse wizard to generate java code from wsdl. Will this create the business logic as well?

Tags: java, tomcat, migration, websphere, apache-axis

I used eclipse wizard to generate java code from WSDL. Will this create the business logic as well? I am actually working on a migration project to migrate web applications and web services from WebSphere onto Tomcat.

I was successfully able to generate some code using the eclipse wizard and the existing WSDL. Can anyone who has knowledge on the process please educate me so that i can migrate my web services from WebSphere to Tomcat using Apache Axis2. I want to get rid of all the WebSphere dependencies too.

Comment: Isn't the business logic by definition the thing that can't be auto-generated?

Comment: I would warmly suggest to use Spring-WS, which promotes contract-first Web Services.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - I am compelled to use Apache Axis2. Hence i am stuck with using the same. :(

Comment: @djechlin - Should i write the business logic for the entire codebase?

Comment: You are migrating a project from WebSphere to Tomcat - you only need to touch the websphere-specific parts, are the webservices websphere-specific?

Comment: @burna - Few of the components are WebSphere specific,

Comment: @sandy I'm just curious, what exactly is websphere specific

Comment: @burna - it uses WebSphere specific API, like WebSphere Stub, base64 etc.

Comment: Using JAX-WS there shouldn't be any WebSphere dependencies. You must provide more details (where exactly do you use proprietary WAS APIs?).

Answer (score 1):

Using Eclipse to generate the classes from a WSDL will simply give you an easy way to work with the entities defined by the WSDL.

Whilst it's not possible for Eclipse to auto-generate your business logic, you may be able to refactor the existing logic to work with the Axis2 classes. Perhaps taking a look at an Axis 2 client tutorial would help? You can also look into Spring-WS to handle things like marshalling and message sending to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you please suggest me any link to some documentation which can help me in refactoring the existing logic to work with the Axis2 classes. Any relevant implemented examples would help a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere supports two Web service stacks: JAX-RPC and JAX-WS. JAX-WS (the more modern one of the two) is designed such that the application code is portable and doesn't have any dependencies on container specific classes. JAX-RPC on the other hand heavily relies on code generation and although it is standardized, the generated code will have dependencies on container specific classes. JAX-RPC based Web services are still portable to some extend, but you need to regenerate the generated code when moving from one implementation to the other.

You mentioned that the existing code "uses WebSphere specific API, like WebSphere Stub, base64". That suggests that your application uses JAX-RPC. If your objective is to migrate that code to Tomcat **without rewriting it entirely**, then the most cost efficient way would be to use a JAX-RPC implementation on Tomcat, such as Axis 1.4. In that case, regenerating the relevant code with the Axis 1.4 tooling should allow you to get rid of WebSphere dependencies.

Comment: Can i get any reference documentation to the solution that you have proposed above which i can refer to?